# How do I add to wishlist programatically?

Tags: wishlist

I have scoured the web yet I am no nearer to understanding how I add a product to the wishlist in code.

I have a product ID and a customer object in my controller and I just want to be able to add that product to that customer's wishlist. It is not rocket science I am after, just something that should be doable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the code you need can be found in `app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php` method `_addItemToWishList`.

You will need to load the product by it's ID and load the wish list by customer. The code would look roughly something like this.

```
$wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customerId, true);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

$buyRequest = new Varien_Object(array()); // any possible options that are configurable and you want to save with the product

$result = $wishlist->addNewItem($product, $buyRequest);
$wishlist->save();
```

Just out of curiosity. Why not use the `addAction` provided by the wishlist controller to add the products?

You can obtain the url via `echo Mage::helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($product);`

Comment: I want to do an ajax 'add to' from a modal, with things like 'how many others have it in their wishlist' being part of the display. I actually copied the addAction to 'ajaxAction' in the normal controller, so I have something that works. Just got to tidy it up and put it into my own module. Nonetheless I am surprised that there is no convenient method and that I have to extend the wishlist controller class - a bit hackish to me!!! No idea what it does with 'buyRequest', luckily I don't need it. Anyway, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Note that if you want to add a (configured) configurable product to your wishlist the array in the Varien_Object should have the following keys: e.g. `product='99', qty='1', super_attribute[133]='3'`

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi use this code to remove a product having productid **$productId** of a customer having customerid **$customerId**.

   $itemCollection = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->getCollection()
                        ->addCustomerIdFilter($customerId);
        foreach($itemCollection as $item) {
             if($item->getProduct()->getId() == $productId){
                $item->delete();
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_GET['addmultiple'] == "cartitem")
{


        $cuu = $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
        $currentUrl = str_replace("?addmultiple=cartitem","",$cuu);

    try{
            $cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();
            $ms="";
            $myupsell_product = $_product->getUpSellProductCollection();
            $myupsell_product->AddStoreFilter();
            foreach($myupsell_product as $upsellprd)
        {

            $params = 1;
            $pid = $upsellprd->getId();
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);;
            $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            $msg .= $product->getName(). " is successfully added into cart<br>";
        }
         $cart->save();
         Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('checkout')->__($msg));
         header("Refresh: 0; url=$currentUrl");     


    }
    catch(Exception $e) 
    {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('checkout')->__($e->getMessage()));
        header("Refresh: 0; url=$currentUrl");     


    }

}
```