# Add automatically a product to wishlist after order is done

Tags: magento-1.9, products, order-status, wishlist

I’m supposed to move to the wishlist, all the items that i've got in the cart but straight after the order is complete.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Here is my code:

in /app/etc/modules/Eleva_ObserverFromCartToWishlist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Eleva_ObserverFromCartToWishlist>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Eleva_ObserverFromCartToWishlist>
    </modules>
</config>
```

in /app/code/local/Eleva/ObserverFromCartToWishlist/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Eleva_ObserverFromCartToWishlist>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Eleva_ObserverFromCartToWishlist>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <eleva_observerfromcarttowishlist>
                <class>Eleva_ObserverFromCartToWishlist_Model</class>
            </eleva_observerfromcarttowishlist>
        </models>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <Eleva_ObserverFromCartToWishlist_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Eleva_ObserverFromCartToWishlist_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>addfromcarttoWishlistEvent</method>
                    </Eleva_ObserverFromCartToWishlist_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

in /app/code/local/Eleva/ObserverFromCartToWishlist/Model/observer.php

```
<?php

class Eleva_ObserverFromCartToWishlist_Model_Observer {

    public function addfromcarttoWishlistEvent(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();

        //assuming the customer check out as a register user
        $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($order->getCustomerId(), true);

        foreach($items as $item){
           $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
           //Todo - add the options
           $buyRequest = new Varien_Object(array()); // any possible options that are configurable and you want to save with the product
           $result = $wishlist->addNewItem($product, $buyRequest);
        } 

        $wishlist->save();

        $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite($myfile, "test");
        fclose($myfile);

        Mage::log($order);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you added as an answer, since it doesn't work

Comment: Also what type of product did you purchase, simple product with or without option, configureable or bundle? Did you check to make sure your observer was be executed?

Comment: I did purchase a simple product without any option.

Comment: Did you check to make sure your observer was be executed?

Comment: Yeah i'm sure that my observer was be executed. Where am i wrong?
I updated the code above.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Did you check your error log?

Comment: No, i didn't. But now it works, i don't know why. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [How do I add to wishlist programatically?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19678/how-do-i-add-to-wishlist-programatically) and [magento sales_order_place_after observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154071/magento-sales-order-place-after-observer)

In your observer

```
<?php
class Feed_Sales_Model_Order_Observer
{

    public function addToWishlist($observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();

        //assuming the customer check out as a register user
        $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($order->getCustomerId(), true);

        foreach($items as $item){
           $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
           //Todo - add the options
           $buyRequest = new Varien_Object(array()); // any possible options that are configurable and you want to save with the product
           $result = $wishlist->addNewItem($product, $buyRequest);
        } 

        $wishlist->save();         
    }
}
?>
```