# Magento 1.4 wishlist - where is additional configuration data stored?

Tags: wishlist, magento-1.4

I found the following code for adding an item to a wishlist with configuration

```
$wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customerId, true);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

//NOTE! I'm not sure this array format is correct so that may be the problem
$buyRequest = new Varien_Object(array('color'=>'blue','size'=>'large')); // any possible options that are configurable and you want to save with the product

$result = $wishlist->addNewItem($product, $buyRequest);
$wishlist->save();
```

The add to wishlist works successfully, except that either a) the color and size configuration are not stored anywhere, b) they're stored somewhere I don't know or c) they're not correct in syntax.  Can someone please narrow this down and clarify?

Comment: To help the community I might add that this code came from this forum here but doesn't discuss my question:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19678/how-do-i-add-to-wishlist-programatically

Answer (score 1):

The array to pass the product options in incorrect. 
You can try like below :

```
$wishlist=Mage::helper('wishlist')->getWishlist();
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$_product = $model->load($productId);
$params = array('product' => $productId,
        'qty' => 1,
        'store_id' => $storeId,
        'options' => array('optionId'=>'optionValue')
    );
$request = new Varien_Object();
$request->setData($params);
$result = $wishlist->addNewItem($_product, $request);
```

Comment: Does the `optionId` need to correspond to anything database-wise? i.e. to an entity_id in some `options_..` table?

Comment: Also to note, my question is to where the option information is actually stored.